# " to " VS " until "

Tags: prepositions

Peter is far from a procrastinator.

> A. He never leaves today's work undone until tomorrow.
>
> B. He never leaves today's work undone to tomorrow.

**to** VS **until**, which is better ?  A or B?

Or are there any other ways of saying the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

Sentences A and B convey slightly different things about Peter, depending on the context.

In sentence A, Peter is *somewhat* a procrastinator, because he may cram today's work in the last hour before tomorrow . . . This is caused by the word "until", which communicates a time duration for Peter's activities closing in on tomorrow.

In sentence B, Peter is certain that he does all today's work, and doesn't leave it to tomorrow, because he is not a procrastinator. This sounds perfectly fine to me.

Another problem I had with sentence A is that it is slightly ambiguous. It reminds me of this paradox: "Procrastinate now, don't wait." In other words, if you follow the command, are you or aren't you procrastinating now?

It is possible to interpret sentence A as saying that Peter doesn't only leave today's work undone *today*, but waits until tomorrow to *leave* it undone. He doesn't only procrastinate today, but waits until tomorrow to leave it undone. Who knows when he will do it?

So, I would opt for sentence B for the above two reasons.

Comment: Everything you've said here is sound +1. But, I think the construction itself can be better managed. See my answer.  I'm curious to hear your take.

Answer (score 1):

Without stepping on Cuc's toes…

I think that there is an inherent oddity in both sentences.

It took me two reads through to figure out why they bothered me. But, I believe there is a competing concept in the same sentence making it a bit redundant.

Leaves off and undone mean essentially the same thing in this sentence. (Not identical, mind you, contextually the same.)

I would say either:

> He never leaves off today's work until tomorrow.

-Or-

> He never leaves today's work undone (until tomorrow).

The parenthetical portion is optional.

Both convey that Peter is no procrastinator without sounding redundant.

If you wish to use the to construction, it sounds better in my ear without off:

> He never leaves today's work to tomorrow.

Grammatically I cannot explain that. But, it rings cleaner in my ears.

Comment: Well, you're indicating a possible tautology or pleonasm. 
To "leave off" is a verb phrase, but "leave undone" is also correct. It may be theoretically possible to assume that "leave undone" is a tautology of "leave off" + "leave undone", or a pleonasm of "leave off" + "undone", but I find both alternatives a bit construed. It is grammatically correct to say "leave [work] undone".

Alternatively, I earlier considered that "to leave work" and "to leave work undone" are also competing here. The first addresses that one goes home, the second that there was more to do. "Undone" clears that up.

Comment: @cuc I'm not sure I follow your statement. I am not arguing the validity of leave + undone. Nor am I saying that leave off is incorrect, either. I wouldn't even say that all three together are not grammatical. Just a bit … unpleasant to the ear.   Undone is, of course, optional but can serve to clarify. I believe us to be on the same side of the argument, but I found your statement a bit hard to follow without a pen and paper.  The one thing I wouldn't say leave undone to tomorrow. That just sounds a bit off.

Comment: Sorry, I did not want to criticize you, just meander a little bit. I may have misunderstood you, but all is well. I meant to clarify your option to use "leave off" instead. It seems it did not work well. It's just what it is, we try to make it better. I think your final sentence is true, the use of "undone" here sounds a bit off. But what do you think about a modification of B: "He never leaves today's undone work to tomorrow"?

Comment: @Cuc No worries.  :-)